# Why does git not ignore blank lines?

Tags: git, git-diff

For next final code:

[image]

I want to see what is changed: `git diff -b -w --ignore-blank-lines`

[image]

the line of code `$data =  [ map{ { id => $_-> id, ip => $_->ip } } $firewall->all ];` is displayed as moved, but it is not moved.

with `--ignore-blank-lines` option I expect next result:

[image]

```
$ git --version
git version 2.24.0
```

I get expected result only if I manually in source delete 688, 689 lines.

Why git do not ignore 688, 689 lines?

Comment: Do you want Git to format your code, or do you want to hide these blank lines?

Comment: What does `-b -w` stand for?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden: This blank lines should be hidden as on `expected` picture

Comment: @mx0: `-w --ignore-all-space`, `-b --ignore-space-change` correspondingly

Comment: You could try `git diff -b -w --ignore-blank-lines | grep -v '^\+$'` to hide these lines.

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` never promises to show you what you *actually* did, nor some *particular way* of achieving the result you achieved.  It promises only to show *some set of added and deleted lines* (or in word-diff mode, words) that will achieve the same result.

That aside, with the various ignore-white-space-changes options, it seems odd that Git would choose to display a sequence that says "delete some lines, then put some of them back".  Note that it also said to delete the original `### Change NAS Config` and then add back a new `### Change NAS Config` that visually (i.e., disregarding any white space changes such as tabs-vs-spaces) appears identical.

The way to debug and/or diagnose this would be to provide the actual before-and-after files, or some subset of them that continues to show the same `git diff` behavior when running `git diff --no-index options old-file new-file`, to someone who has the time and interest in figuring out why `git diff` presented a diff that was at least *visually* sub-optimal.

The actual algorithm involved attempts to find a change that has the fewest possible *instructions*, which tends to preserve existing lines, but if it can preserve multiple existing (but visually-irrelevant) lines while deleting and then re-adding some other existing (visually-relevant) lines, it may choose the one that looks worse to humans, but is equally or more efficient with respect to the number-of-changes count.

The *`options`* for ignoring white space are meant to make the result more visually-relevant, but in this case seem to be failing.  Having actual input files that trigger this case is crucial to figuring out why.  I have some interest in this area, but not enough time to work on it.  In any case all we can say here on StackOverflow is that this *is* normal: diffs do not promise to be as useful to you as you might like.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of `git diff` (`git help diff` or https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---ignore-blank-lines):

> --ignore-blank-lines
>
> Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.

So, the option ignores **diff changes** that do only contain blank lines but still shows them.

See my test:

I created a new file containing `Hello`, 2 spaces and `World`.
Then, I executed `git init` and `git add .`
After I removed one blank line and called `git diff` and `git diff --ignore-blank-lines`.

`git diff`:

```
 Hello

-
 World
```

`git diff --ignore-blank-lines`:

```
‍
```

Comment: I have deleted lines and add some empty, but `git diff` shows the 691 line as added. It is not expected.

Comment: I think it shows lines as added if there are non-blank lines changed nearly.

Comment: This is no changes. Only line delations

Comment: A deletion is a change.